# externals webpack not working (same result as without it)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-4

As I understand, `externals` property is to not include the dependency in the final bundle. Am I right?

here is what I do: (i am writing a library).

this is put in webpack's config.

```
externals: {
 JQuery: "jquery"
},
```

and this is my main.js which is also the entry.

```
import JQuery from 'jquery'
```

What really happens is in the final bundle `(main.bundle.js)` , there're **150** occurencies of jquery. Then I remove the externals completely from the webpack config and bundle it again and in `main.bundle.js`, occurence of jquery is still **150**. It doesn't make sense. In the first case, there shouldn't be any occurence (only require) which would run in the client's code (whoever uses my library). Am i missing something?

Comment: Maybe you should try ```externals: { jquery: "jQuery" } ```

Comment: The question is that do I still have to include jquery package in my client code which uses that library? or will that external thing load it at runtime without me including it in client code?